# Lost the IntelliSense in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am running SQL-2008 R2 Server.

Usually when I write a query, I get a full-versed IntelliSense displaying all the objects in my Database.

But now when I was onto a task, it showed no IntelliSense. Instead, when I wrote the object names, it showed that object is invalid! However, running the Query gives correct results.

I shut-down the Management studio and restarted it. Now all works fine.

I wanna know what was actually wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: It's called *IntelliSense*. I corrected that.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You probably needed to refresh it. Either

1. Go to Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache
2. Use `Ctrl+Shift+R`

Comment: You need to have focus on the query window, else this menu item will not appear and Ctrl+Shift+R won't work.

Comment: When you create a new entity in SQL like - table, view, sprc... you need to clear the cache, otherwise you will not have IntelliSense. For me shortcut Ctrl+Shift+R works as a charm on SSMS 18.10

Comment: In SSMS v18 after I "refreshed local cache" intellisense stopped working. I had to disable and enable Intellisense. Top menu,  Query-> Intelisense Enabled. Classic case of "Have you tried turning it off and on... ?" :)

Answer (score 2):

From another question I answered... there is way to auto fresh without having to manually do Control Shift R time.

I found an addin that offers a free community edition addin. SSMS Boost offers some helpful features that bypass the shortcomings of SSMS.

To auto refresh, I setup the shortcut for F5 to Run Query and then Auto Refresh Intellisense. Now, everytime I execute, my intellisense cache is automatically refreshed. Seems to replicate the functionality of auto refresh in Red Gate's SQL Prompt Experimental functionality.

Answer (score 2):

A picture is worth a 1000 words.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To activate IntelliSense for Column Names:

First type the FROM clause (`FROM tblEmps`), then second, go back and type the SELECT clause (`SELECT EmpID, LName`).

This way IntelliSense will help you pick out the Column Names to include in your SELECT statement.

```
SELECT __________
FROM tblEmps
```

The trick here is to type the FROM clause prior to typing the SELECT clause, so IntelliSense knows which Columns to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that sometimes you have to do a database "refresh" ***before*** the Cache refresh step given by others.

[image: Refreshing the database (before Cache refresh step)]