# SQL Server 2008 Intellisense problem

Tags: sql-server-2008, intellisense

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lost the IntelliSense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055911/lost-the-intellisense)

I have created schema in SQL Server 2008 called `CustomerTraining` in the AdventureWorks database. Then created a table called `Customer` like this:

```
create schema CustomerTraining

create table CustomerTraining.Customer
(
CustomerID int not null,
CustomerName nvarchar(25) not null,
TerritoryID int  null,
AccountNumber nvarchar(20) not null,
CustomerType nvarchar(20) not null,
CustomerAddress nvarchar(20) not null,
CustomerPhone nvarchar(20)  null,
CustomerStateCode nchar(2) null
)
```

then I began to insert some record :

```
insert into AdventureWorks.CustomerTraining.Customer
values(1,'Prateek Singh','1','A4B8934561','Internal','Anna Nagar','7418773929','TN')
```

It all works fine for me but in the intellisense its not showing CustomerTraining schema under AdventureWorks database...

Why its not showing ? Can someone help......

Answer (score 13):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to [refresh the intellisense cache](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dtjones/archive/2008/09/11/refreshing-the-intellisense-cache.aspx).

Or if that doesn't work (some SSMS addins hijack this combination) do it through the menu options `Edit -> IntelliSense -> Refresh Local Cache`

[image: Menu screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

Ctrl+shift+R to refresh the cache?