# SQL Server Management Studio: why when inserting into table, foreign key column is not visible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

It's about SQL Server 2012 Management Studio. I'm training my SQL skills as manually create queries.

Now I want to insert several records in the Users table. As you see there exists a column `GroupID`, which is a foreign key to another table `Groups`.

[image]

However when I write a query:

```
insert into Users (Username, Pass, FullName, GroupID)
values ('Tyana', '17890', 'Tyana Stoyanov', 4)
```

I get an error:

> Invalid column name GroupID

[image]

**Why is that?**

Comment: After adding new columns you need to refresh the intellisense cache to have them picked up. Possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 Intellisense problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215211/sql-server-2008-intellisense-problem)

Comment: Yeah, this was it!!! I didn't know this option, though I even tried Disconnect/Connect with no success. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for a well presented question.

Answer (score 5):

Ctrl + Shift + R is the hotkey to refresh Intellisense.  It should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [GroupID]? I meant whether or not you tried using brackets? Also, are you sure that GroupID is not an auto incremental field or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing this? I think it will execute properly. The error is indicated only because of non-refreshed intellisense.