# SQL Server. How to refresh the intellisense?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Lost the IntelliSense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055911/lost-the-intellisense)
> [SQL Server 2008 Intellisense problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215211/sql-server-2008-intellisense-problem)

In SQL Server 2008 R2, I've just imported a new data table and/or renamed fields in an existing table (it happens either way).  When I start to write some SQL, the intellisense doesn't recognize the new field names and starts underlining everything.

The only fix I've found is to close and reopen SQL Server, but I'm sure there's a simpler solution out there. Suggestions please?

(This isn't a serious problem, just a pet peeve).

Answer (score 509, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> will refresh Intellisense.

Comment: You need to have focus on the query window, else this menu item will not appear and Ctrl+Shift+R won't work.

Comment: This intellisense functionality is broken with SQL Server Management Studio version 10.50. It works in 11.0+.

Comment: In other words, in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 2008, it's broken.  In SSMS 2012, intellisense works.  So if you need to connect to MSSQL 2008, just upgrade the IDE to 2012.

Comment: Worth a mention. Ctrl + Shift + R does not always work. Sometimes you have to restart SSMS.

Comment: If you have **SQL Prompt** installed, the shortcut is **Ctrl + Shift + D** or, using the menu, **SQL Prompt > Refresh suggestions**.

Comment: This didn't work for me, but right-click "Intellisense Enabled" (to disable it) then repeat (to re-enable it) did work for me.

Answer (score 140):

If you want to do it via the menus, it's:

```
Edit / IntelliSense / Refresh Local Cache
```

Using the keyboard, it's:
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>