# Why SQL Server built-in IntelliSense can't found table name correctly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

Problem is every-time I created a new table, function, stored procedure, or view,
and I want those names to be available in my IntelliSense during I create a new query, I can't find those names and Intellisense doesn't seem to work.

I've already done several solutions hoping just to work things out but seems not to work at all.

- Refresh table, function, stored procedure, views
- Connect/disconnect the connection

I really don't have an idea on how to solve this problem.

Is there any other options just to solve this problem permanently?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Crtl-Shift-R will refresh intellisense and pick up any changes you just made, as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825287/sql-server-how-to-refresh-the-intellisense

Comment: So this is actually a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate of a question!