# SMSS Falsely Complaining About Invalid Columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

The following code runs and behaves as expected. However, as the image shows, SSMS is complaining that the columns from the `GEN_NEW` sub-select are invalid. (Actual error popping up next to the mouse is  "Invalid column name".)

Am I doing something wrong? How can I convince the SSMS parser that those columns really are valid? It's annoying to have SSMS barking when the code actually works.

```
    MERGE
     INTO
           General.Associate  GA
    USING
           (
             SELECT
                      GEN_ID
                     ,GEN_JSON
               FROM
                      OPENJSON( @jsonResult, '$.entities' )
                      WITH (
                              GEN_ID   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER  '$.id'
                             ,GEN_JSON NVARCHAR(MAX)     '$' AS JSON
                           )
           )  GEN_NEW
           ON GA.GEN_ID = GEN_NEW.GEN_ID
     WHEN  MATCHED
           AND GA.GEN_JSON <> GEN_NEW.GEN_JSON
     THEN  UPDATE
              SET
                   GA.GEN_JSON = GEN_NEW.GEN_JSON
     WHEN  NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
     THEN  INSERT (GEN_JSON)
           VALUES (GEN_NEW.GEN_JSON)
    ;
```

Here's a snapshot of SSMS's complaints:

[image: snapshot of code showing red squigglies]

**SSMS Version:** 19.0.2
**SQL Server Version:** 15.0.2101.7

**Edit:** This is not an intellisense issue as Peter B suggested. The columns in question are part of the sub-query, not something outside the query.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server. How to refresh the intellisense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825287/sql-server-how-to-refresh-the-intellisense)

Comment: No. I'm very familiar with refreshing intellisense.  I'm not sure why that would do it. It's not referencing anything outside the script. But, to confirm, I did it anyway.

Comment: I think it's ridiculous that this is being voted to close. @PeterB Please actually read the post and review the code. You will see that it's not a duplicate of the indicated question.

Comment: Not sure what stackoverflow can do with an ssms bug, but i'll bite. Does it help to add a (GEN_ID,GEN_JSON) column names after GEN_NEW subquery alias?

Comment: @siggemannen Yes! That took care of it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone reported this issue with `OPENJSON` [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/58180945-5146-ec11-a81a-6045bd78b970).  - Bizarrely the below solves the issue (redundant `ColName AS ColName`)

```
USING
       (
         SELECT
                  GEN_ID AS GEN_ID
                 ,GEN_JSON AS GEN_JSON
           FROM
                  OPENJSON( @jsonResult, '$.entities' )
                  WITH (
                          GEN_ID   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER  '$.id'
                         ,GEN_JSON NVARCHAR(MAX)     '$' AS JSON
                       )
       )  GEN_NEW
```

You can also do `GEN_NEW(GEN_ID, GEN_JSON)` as suggested by [@siggemannen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13061224/siggemannen)

Comment: Upvoted the bug report