# SQL Server 2008 management studio intellisense auto refresh (not manually through menu or Keyboard shortcut)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

The intellisense feature in SQL server management studio was long overdue (it was difficult  especially for those used to Visual studio intellisense) and great to see that it is added in SQL Server 2008, but I think it still lacks in one feature. if I make some changes to the schema or add or drop objects, I will have to refresh the intellisense manually (Edit --> intellisense --> refresh local cache). Is there any way to refresh this automatically (may be through some external add-ins or any other way)?

Comment: **Exact** duplicate of [Lost the IntelliSense](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055911/lost-the-intellisense) and many others

Comment: no, it is not a duplicate. I know that I can go through the edit menu or use Key board shortcut to refresh the intellisense manually. I don't have to refresh intellisense in Visual studio if I add a new class and thought it would be nice to have the auto refresh in Management studio as well.

Comment: don't understand why it is voted to be closed. this question is different, I am asking if there is any way to refresh the intellisense automatically without going through the menu or keyboard shortcut. I don't think this question has not been asked before and this is very much related to programming.

Answer (score 12):

No way to do it automatically that I know of.  But the much-quicker way is just to press `Ctrl + Shift + R`.  Quick, easy, and painless.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, there is a way to do this. I found an addin that offers a free community edition addin. SSMS Boost offers some helpful features that bypass the shortcomings of SSMS.

To auto refresh, I setup the shortcut for F5 to Run Query and then Auto Refresh Intellisense. Now, everytime I execute, my intellisense cache is automatically refreshed. Seems to replicate the functionality of auto refresh in Red Gate's SQL Prompt Experimental functionality.