# How to automatically refresh the SQL Server Management Studio intellisense cache?

Tags: sql-server, refresh, intellisense, ssms

In SQL Server Management Studio if the user creates new table columns, tables, etc. the user needs to refresh the IntelliSense cache using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Is there a setting or some way to automate this so it can automatically be refreshed right after inserting a new table, etc?

Comment: Almost duplicate with:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020440/sql-server-2008-management-studio-intellisense-auto-refresh-not-manually-throug

Comment: Just FYI the other answer talks about a CodePlex add-in called "SSMS Boost" but I can't locate this add-in on CodePlex anymore.

Comment: I also couldn't find it on CodePlex but did find a commercial version of it but I couldn't tell from the web site if it did the auto refreshing of the cache though. Hopefully someone will do a free version for the whole community. That will be very useful for everyone. :-)

Comment: SSMSBoost is not hosted on codeplex, it is currently free and you can find on it's website (.com). As creator of this add-in i could add functionality that you need. It has good chances to be possible to implement. But what do you expect?  Timer - based refresh?  Or monitoring executed sql statements?  UI- based changes will not be detected. Please, provide more info.

Comment: I think that a timer that the user can set would be perfect. :-)

Comment: @AndreiRantsevich, sorry to bother you asking for it here after four years, but what has happened with the plans of this feature?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I don't know that there is a way to automatically refresh the cache without manually pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (or equivalent, e.g. the menu). The reason is that when the app talks to the database too much, people complain that it is too chatty (perhaps someone could write a simple add-in that does this - using something like [query notifications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130764.aspx) to indicate something has changed in the metadata views?). You may also want to consider an add-on like SSMS Boost (though with a quick keyword search I see no mention of this functionality on its [feature page](http://www.ssmsboost.com/VersionCompare)) or SQL Prompt (but also I don't see any evidence of this functionality [in their documentation](http://documentation.red-gate.com/display/SP6/SQL+Prompt+6+documentation), only a [mention here of an experimental feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10516731/61305)).

I believe [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx) does this, but I don't know if you can control the frequency of the refresh. And using that tool may also require a significant shift in how you think about database development.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes, it would be nice to see if someone will create that add-in. I will look for SSMS Boost as Aaron suggested to see if I can find that one.